# HTML5 Video to play when buttons are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

On my site I have a short video of me playing, without controls, in a loop in the top left corner, a bit like Holly from Red Dwarf. I want to click on a button and replace the video with another, then when the video has played I want to go back to the first video.  There is be 5 buttons to click, playing 5 videos, one at a time of cause.

I'm not that savvy with JavaScript to do this, I would appreciate any help on how to do this with HTML5 video.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you done so far?  Have you tried any JavaScript or done any research prior to this?  Any code-blocks of your current setup would be helpful.

Comment: I've looked online for some tutorials, but they just show how to click on a button to play a video, but not replace a video, then play it, then replace that video with the original one.  I've done something similar with audio but on mouseover, placing all the audio in article tags and preloading the audio, it works, I'm thinking something similar with video, but I just need to select them...

Comment: I was thinking you may put your video inside a div and call javascript on your button press that would replace the contents of that div with your new video.  However, I'm not yet sure how you would redirect the user back to your original video, short of a timer (which doesn't work the best with buffering time, etc).

Answer (score 0):

To change the video on button press, you could have a javascript function which replaces the current video with the one you'd like to play.

If you know the length of the video you will be playing, you could use a Javascript timer to replace the new one when it finishes.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/cHn3L/1/

Page Code:

```
<div id="vid">
    <iframe width="236" height="105" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/AGg3u03JPfk?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<h1>Change Video</h1>
<button onclick="PlayVid()">Change Video</button>
```

Javascript:

```
resetVid = function() {
    //get the Video div and replace with the original video source code
    var videoPanel = document.getElementById('vid');
    videoPanel.innerHTML = '<iframe width="236" height="105" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/AGg3u03JPfk?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';    
}

PlayVid = function() {
    //get the Video div and play new video on button click
    var videoPanel = document.getElementById('vid');
    videoPanel.innerHTML = '<iframe width="280" height="157" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ldT8qxWh07Y?autoplay=1&start=17" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

    //replace video after 8.5 seconds
    setTimeout(resetVid, 8500);
}
```

This could potentially be an issue with timing if your video takes time to buffer/load, in which case the new video may prematurely switch back to the original.

Comment: Let me know if you have questions or further issues, and please mark as answer if this works for you =)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, plus I am using the HTML5 Video tag to display the videos not iframes, but this didn't work either way...

Comment: It shouldn't matter what types of tags you are using.  Please share your code so that I can help you with what you have.  The important part is that you will be writing the HTML5 video tags with javascript instead of iFrames.